# Expectation problem from a question paper.

Tags: statistics, expectation

Suppose that a point is chosen at random on a stick of unit length and that the stick is broken into two pieces at that point. Find the expected value of the length of the longer piece.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you construct a probability space suitable to analyze this scenario?

Comment: Well I was refering to Uniform distribution. Let X: denote the distance of the chosen point from one side, so we can say X ~ U(0,1). Now being broken there are two parts of length X and (1 - X) respectively. Now (1-X) ~ U(0,1). But this approach isn't correct I suppose. 

Comment: @ Soumajit Das  The longer piece is with equal probability anything between 1/2 and 1. Hence its average length is 3/4.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the coordinate of the dividing point in the interval $(0,1)$. Then, $X \sim\mathsf{Uniform}(0,1)$.

Define $Y = \max\{X,1 − X\}$ so that
$$Y =\begin{cases}
1 − X, & 0 < X < \frac12\\
X, & \frac12 \le X < 1.
\end{cases}
$$
It then follows that possible values for $Y$ range between $1/2$ and 1. Computing the cdf for $Y$ we then have that, for $\frac12< y < 1$,
$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=\Bbb P(Y\le y)\\
&=\Bbb P\left(1 − X \le y,X < \frac12 \right)+\Bbb P\left(X \le y,X > \frac12 \right)\\
&=\Bbb P\left(1 -y \le X < \frac12 \right)+\Bbb P\left(\frac12<X\le y \right)\\
&=\frac12-(1-y)+y-\frac12
\end{align}
$$
since $X \sim\mathsf{Uniform}(0,1)$ so that
$$
F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}2y-1&\frac12 <y< 1\\
0& \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
Differentiating with respect to $y$ we then get that
$$
f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}2&\frac12 <y< 1\\
0& \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
that is $Y \sim\mathsf{Uniform}(1/2,1)$. It then follows that
$$
\Bbb E(Y)=\frac{1/2+1}{2}=\frac34
$$